# Equation of a circle and implicit function

Tags: functions, circles

I know that the equation of a circle is an implicit function. Why is it an implicit function although we can explicitly represent the function $x^{2} + y^{2} = a^{2}$ as $y = \pm\sqrt{a^{2} - x^{2}}$?

Suppose that we are examining the change of dependent variable with the change of independent variable.

In the latter equation mentioned above, we can consider that $y$ is the dependent variable and $x$ is the independent variable for a while.

Now if we observe the change in $y$ with the change in $x$, it will be a little bit confusing since $\pm$ is associated with the function.

So is this the reason why the equation of a circle is considered to be an implicit function?

Comment: Because the explicit representation $y=f(x)=\pm\sqrt{\cdots}$ is **not a function** in the usual sense of the word since $f$ maps each $x$ to two distinct images.

Comment: You can express the circle as a parametric function, if you want

Comment: Note that whether something is "implicit" or not *only* refers to the form in which it's specified, not "what it is". You could specify a standard $y=x^2$ parabola in a different way as an implicit function if you wanted to!

Comment: Thanks @Prasun Biswas.....didn't notice that earlier

Comment: Can we specify an equation of a straight line as an implicit function too? @thorimur

Comment: Yes, we can: consider $ax+by+c=0$ given constants $a,b,c$.